# How to simplify the summation of a recurrence relation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, recurrence

After solving the recurrence relation `T(n) = 3T(n/3) + nlogn`

I get following equation: `T(n)=3kT(n/3k)+ nlogn + nlog(n/3) + nlog(n/3^2) …nlog(n/3^k)`

How can I simplify the summation and how to know the asymptotic function?

Answer (score 0):

`log a + log b = log(a*b)`, so something like
`T(n) = 3kT(n/3k) + n^k*logn(\Pi_k(n/(3^k)))`

product of 1/(3^k) (`\Pi_k(1/(3^k))`) is
`3^(-1/2k(k+1))`
so
it simplifies
the logs become the single term `n*log{3^(-1/2k(k+1)) * n^(k+1)}`

that takes care of the simplification i gues..